# Encapsulating C# List through method call

Tags: c#, encapsulation

In C# when I want to encapsulate a List I place it inside of a class and throw some helper methods in there with it. However, what I have noticed is that whenever I want to iterate over the list of items I just return the list. Simple. However, what is bad about this is that I am unable to tell if the list has been modified by some method gone wrong.

So this is what I have been doing:

```
class Animals
{
    private List<Dog> _dogs;

    public List<Dog> Dogs
    {
        get { return _dogs; }
    }

}
```

To conteract this I thought of doing:

```
class Animals
{
    private List<Dog> _dogs;

    public Dog GetDog(int dogid)
    {
        return _dogs[dogid];
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _dogs.Count; }
    }
}
```

My real issue with this method lies in the fact that every single time I want an item from the list, a method must be called. This means that if I want to iterate over the list, I must setup a loop to go for `Animals.Count` number of times calling `Animals.GetDog(i)` every iteration.

Is this going to affect my program? Is there a more suitable way of accomplishing the same thing?

I've had a look at ways of encapsulating Lists, but they seem quite intricate. My main aim is to not expose `_dogs` list to anything outside of the class.

Comment: Why you do not want to expose list at the first place? Just asking, because without the answer it is hard to tell how to help you.

Comment: I don't really get your problem. What exactly is it that you want to do?

Comment: I don't want to expose the underlying list because doing so allows outside classes to modify values in the list without the container class even being aware.

Comment: It's also to allow me to create helper methods without being confused about whether I call the method on the list or the container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an IEnumerable to encapsulate the list quite easily:

```
public IEnumerable<Dog> GetDogs()
{
    foreach (Dog dog in _dogs)
    {
        yield return dog;
    }
}
```

This allows you to enumerate the list from outside the class, but not have access to the underlying list.

```
//Outside Animals class
foreach (Dog dog in animalObj.GetDogs())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I like this very much! I had to look around to actually see what it meant, but I can see some value in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than a `List`:

```
public class Animals
{
    public Animals()
    {
        myModifiableDogList = new List<Dog>();
        Dogs = new ReadOnlyCollection<Dog>(myModifiableDogList);
    }

    private IList<Dog> myModifiableDogList;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Dog> Dogs { get; private set; }
}
```

This way you can make changes to the list, not allowing anyone else accessing the `Dogs` property to change it. This also allows the user to always have an updated collection, as opposed to always returning a copy of the list.

Comment: You could also return myModifiableDogList.AsReadOnly();

Answer (score 1):

A pretty common approach to solve your problem to return a read only snapshot of your list, e.g.

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<Dog> Snapshot
{
    get
    {
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<Dog>(_dogs);
    }
}
```